# Google Sheets QUERY returning wrong values using >date

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

## Note: Australian date format (DD/MM/YYYY) below.

I have the following formula on Sheet2:

```
=QUERY ('Sheet1'!$A:$B, "select B where (A>date'"&text ($C$3, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"')", 0)
```

The source data on Sheet1 ($A:$B) looks like:

- 26/05/2015   A1
- 26/05/2015   A2
- 26/05/2015   A3
- 10/11/2015 A4
- 02/01/2015 A5
- 21/07/2015 A6
- 24/12/2015 A7
- 24/12/2015 A8
- 25/12/2015 A9
- 27/08/2015 A10

The value stored in $C$3 on sheet2 is manually entered, but is currently set to "01/12/2015".

When I run the query it returns me with these values in my data set

- 10/11/2015
- 02/01/2015
- 21/07/2015
- 24/12/2015
- 24/12/2015
- 25/12/2015
- 27/08/2015

Why is the greater than not working for my dates?

e.g. I'm asking the query to give me all dates that occur after the 01/12/2015, but am receiving dates before then (even if the dates were doing something funny with the AU/US date format, it still doesn't make sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A FILTER formula may work instead:

`=FILTER(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A>C3)`